# Ajax request failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do an AJAX request to an api that provides weather data, for some reason the request keeps failing. I've tried to use a .fail() callback to grab an error message; the function gets called, but it only gives me empty strings to work with.

This is the code I'm using

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

long = position.coords.longitude;
lat = position.coords.latitude;
console.log(long);
console.log(lat);

url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + encodeURIComponent(lat) + "&lon=" + encodeURIComponent(long) + "&APPID=" + encodeURIComponent(apikey);

console.log(url);

$.getJSON(url, function(response){
console.log("Success");
console.log(response);
}).fail(function(obj, stat, err){ console.log(err)});

});
```

The url I get on the console conforms perfectly to the api's standards, right down to the 'http' in the beginning. I've made sure the longitudes and latitudes are being properly fetched too. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ignore any uninitialized or seemingly global variables, they're all sorted out in a different segment before this code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine Check this example. I will be changing my api so make sure you check it before i change it.

Try pasting the result of `console.log(url);` to your browser and check if you get the desired output. Because i think there is a problem in your `API`

```js
function func(){

lat = 37;
lon = 53;
apikey = "YOUR API";

url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + encodeURIComponent(lat) + "&lon=" + encodeURIComponent(lon) + "&APPID=" + encodeURIComponent(apikey);

console.log(url);

$.getJSON(url, function(response){
console.log("Success");
console.log(response);
}).fail(function(obj, stat, err){ console.log(err)});
  
}

func();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Surprisingly, your snippet works while mine still refuses to.

Comment: have you checked your api

Comment: or try your url on browser

Comment: it seems to be a problem internal to codepen. Thank you for your help :).